# WinForms datagrid inverted so that column headers become (repeating) row labels

Tags: winforms, datagrid, label

I'm looking to display multiple records in a data-aware WinForms grid control, such that the column-headers become (repeating) row-labels. Does the grid of any of the major third-party WinForms control vendors have this feature, or can it be done with the built-in grid control? Or is there a way to simulate it using labels and textboxes and datepickers in a control that offers repeating vertical groups?

```
City   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
State  xx
Zip    xxxxx 
Note   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-------
City   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
State  xx
Zip    xxxxx 
Note   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-------
City   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
State  xx
Zip    xxxxx 
Note   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to simulate it using labels and textboxes and
>   datepickers in a control that offers repeating vertical groups?

You can use either of these options:

- **DataReapter**
  You can use a [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488280.aspx) control.

  > The Visual Basic Power Packs [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx) control is a scrollable
  >   container for controls that display repeated data, for example, rows
  >   in a database table. It can be used as an alternative to the
  >   `DataGridView` control when you need more control over the layout of the
  >   data. The `DataRepeater` "repeats" a group of related controls by
  >   creating multiple instances in a scrolling view. This enables users to
  >   view several records at the same time.
- **Custom UserControl shown in TableLayoutPanel or FlowLayoutPanel**
  You can create a custom `UserControl` which shows a record this way and then using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` show all records.
- **Custom DataGridViewColumn**
  You can create a custom `DataGridViewColumn` hosting a complex (user control) which shows the whole object behind the row this way.

Comment: Thanks. I had not heard about the DataRepeater. Will look at it, and also explore the other options.